# Calculating my location based on known location

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

This question is linked to [Can known object be used to back-calculate my location?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035863/can-known-object-be-used-to-back-calculate-my-location/1035869#1035869) (been almost a month, figured it would be best to start a new question.)

I have a map, and I know which way true north is. I also have marked a known location on that map. I know my distance from that location, as well as my bearing relative to the location. Based on that info, I've been trying to come up with a formula for how to back-calculate MY location. I've been messing around with some trig formulas to get it, but I just don't understand how I would get my location. Like I said in the linked question, my distance from that known location obviously means how far I am. But I'm confused on the angles part, and any help would be great! A drawing might best help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with this image I found that is kind of the reverse of your situation.  In this image the coordinates are known and the bearing is calculated. 
[image]

Let's say $(x_0,y_0)$ is the location you know.  You can set up a right triangle using your known bearings to figure out what amount you need to add or subtract to your $x$ value and your $y$ value.

**EDIT**: So, you know $(x_0,y_0)$ and your bearing from $(x_0,y_0)$.  Assuming you are expressing bearing as the angle from NORTH going clockwise, you can express your coordinates as $$(x_0+d(\sin(\beta)),y_0+d(\cos(\beta)))$$

Note that $\sin(\beta)$ goes with $x$ instead of the standard $y$ you might be used to with the unit circle.  This is because normal degrees start with EAST on the unit circle, but these bearings start with zero at NORTH.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Wouldn't I have to know the x,y values of my location first though to do that? Or, would it be something like doing the distance formula backwards?

Comment: I'll edit my answer...

Comment: Okay so, bearing is sort of set up like a speedometer on a car? 0 on the left, 360 on the right? Maybe if we used some numbers I could see it a little better. Let's say my x,y coordinates of the known location are (2, 4) and the bearing is 30 degrees. The hypotenuse is 20.

Comment: Bearing is usually 0 = NORTH, 90 = EAST, 180 = SOUTH, 270 = WEST, 360 = NORTH again.  In your example, you are 20 from (2,4) at a bearing of 30 degrees, I'd say your location is $(2+20(\sin(30^{\circ})),4+20(\cos(30^{\circ})))$ = $(12,21.32)$

Comment: Oh! Alright this is starting to make sense. Just one question about the bearing here. From what I learned, bearing is the direction you are facing. So if I say my bearing relative to the object is 30 degrees, is that 30 degrees I'm facing sort of north-east away from the object? As in, I need to go northeast to reach that object?

Comment: This is the kind of confusing point.  In my calculations, when I was using 30 degrees, I was using it as, you traveled on the bearing of 30 degrees from the known point.  Meaning you TRAVELED sort of north-east.  Sort of the opposite of what you were saying.  If you are saying you would travel at a bearing of 30 degrees(north-east) to get back to the object, then for my formula to work you would need to add 180 degrees to 30 to get the bearing from the object to your current location.  (so much easier to explain when you have a whiteboard or pen and paper).

Comment: Hmm. Alright I think I'll be using the first one. Just to give some background info, I'm trying to make a game program. Basically, the user enters the coordinates and distance of a known location on a map as well as a bearing for their location in relation to that known location. Then I wanted to back-calculate their actual location. From there, they could choose a point to travel to (by triangulating from their location and the known location). So they wouldn't exactly be traveling to or from the known location.